# Making a simple one-page website ready for browsing on iPhone

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari, mobile-website

I'm very new to web design and just made a simple one page website for my iOS app [here](http://thefalconapp.com). I now want to make it so that when this page is opened on an iPhone, the whole thing is zoomed out enough because right now the right half of the page doesnt show. From my understanding and [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244387/building-a-single-page-compatible-for-mobile-where-to-start) [so far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701919/retrofit-existing-web-page-with-mobile-css), I need to use media queries and create a separate CSS stylesheet for mobile. However I feel like for such a simple page there should be an easier solution with some plug-and-play code. Something consisting of a simple conditional-type statement checking if the user is on mobile, and if so, gives the new dimensions of the page. I don't really know anything except for the very basics of html, css, and javascript when it comes to web development, so simple explanations would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you have to go for http://www.jquerymobile.com it is very good framework for mobile web.

Comment: wow thanks Alone, this is great. I just used it and made a simple page that's almost exactly what I wanted. Now I gotta figure out how to detect a mobile browser and redirect it and I'll be good. Thanks again!

Comment: look [here](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) about detecting mobile browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to go for http://www.jquerymobile.com it is very good framework for mobile web.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a mobile-specific page you might want to experiment with the [viewport meta-tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag). The tag isn't used by desktop browsers, but it scales the size of what you see on a mobile device's screen. You can also check out [Apple's guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html) for more information.